# Is it safe to have source_port_range = "*" as a setting in Azure?

Tags: azure, terraform

Given the default Azure Network Security Group Rules,  for Terraform code below that presents a possible security concern: wouldn't it be having the inbound port_range of "*", considered a security risk?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended value for source port ranges is " * " or Any, and this is because port filtering, as Microsoft notes here, is typically used with a destination port. So, we can leave this at"  * " for Any as well.

Please refer below links  For further information:

.[Network Security Rule](https://cloudacademy.com/course/implementing-azure-network-security/network-security-rules/).

.[terraform-azurerm-network-security-group](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/network-security-group/azurerm/latest).